# Call function in for loop is not passing values

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a sub that passes 2 values to another sub named "getAvgStockData(ticker, exchange)" that pulls data from the web regarding a companies historical prices and calculates a moving average.

The sub I a working on reads the data from a table row by row to pass 2 strings to getAvgStockData(ticker,symbol) which pulls the data and does the calculation.

For some reason not able to pass the 2 strings using the below code, any ideas? Thank you in advance!!!

```
Sub getAllAvgStockData()

 On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim companySymbols As Range

    Set companySymbols = Worksheets("ALL Public Companies").Range("companyRange")

    For Each Row In companySymbols.Rows
       Call getAvgStockData(companySymbols.Rows(tickerSymbol.cellvalue), 
         companySymbols.Rows(exchangeSymbol.cellvalue))         
    Next Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The code should loop through the whole range of companies in a dynamic range table.

Comment: Can you share the `getAvgStockData` code as well? Also, if you comment out or remove `On Error Resume Next`, what error occurs, if any?

Comment: If you are passing strings, this is unlikely to be a string, because is an entire row (or more depending on `tickerSymbol` value) `companySymbols.Rows(tickerSymbol.cellvalue)` (or the other one). You mean to pass only `Call getAvgStockData(tickerSymbol.cellvalue, exchangeSymbol.cellvalue)` instead? Would probably be good to know what `tickerSymbol` or `exchangeSymbol` are too.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I commented out the "ON Error..." part and i get a runtime error on at the Call command saying Object Required.

Comment: And what range does `companyRange` represent?

Comment: the range is a table of company data that is mostly populated using the getAvgStockData() sub.

Comment: i think i might just be getting mixed up on the syntax to read data from column row by row and to pass that value to another sub.